# SIOD error while installing festival in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, text-to-speech, festival

While I try to install my festival speech synthesis system following SIOD error creating problem.

```
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable: voice_cmu_us_slt_arctic_hts
festival: text modes, caught error_ and tidying up
```

Comment: try adding this to your ~/.festivalrc: `(set! debug-output t)
(set_backtrace t)` to get some more information about what the issue is.

Comment: Well, thanks Beau. The problem was solved. It was the  libncurses package missing. So festival failed to compile. I had installed this package and get my work done.